# Windows 10, Lenovo G50

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 is failing to boot.

In safe mode it fails with an error code `0xc0000218 {Registry File Failure}`. I have also had 'Bad System Config Info'.

The system also fails on the 'System Restore' option, when choosing that option from the Startup Menus 'Choose An Option'/'Troubleshoot'/'Advanced Options'. I now want to try the 'Refresh Your PC' option, rebuilding Windows 10 but preserving files.

Unfortunately earlier I went in to the Command Prompt and typed `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions true` because diagnosis prior to the Startup Menus was taking so long. This tells the system to go straight to Safe Mode booting options.

Now I can't get BACK to the 'Refresh Your PC' option, since the system immediately goes to 'Startup Settings' AFTER the 'Choose an Option' screen - all I can do in 'Startup Settings' is retry Safe Mode boot which again fails.

Anyone have a clue how force the system back to the Command Prompt, so I can then UNDO the `bcedit` command?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a recovery drive and type the command

bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions false

Actually, you can perform an in-place upgrade to fix the boot issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. However I still have problems.

I have now created a USB recovery drive (Windows 10 ISO file downloaded from Microsoft). Unfortunately, even when the USB is connected and I use the various Lenovo interrupt keys (Esc, f2, f12), it still bypasses the Boot Menu and goes directly to the 9 'Safe Mode booting options'.

This must be because I set 'bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions true' in error.

Any idea how I can FORCE it to boot from the USB Drive? Or FORCE it go to the earlier stage recovery options?

Kind Regards
Andrew